# drupal_render not working in views-exposed-form.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

I put this in the template:

```
<?php print drupal_render($form['title']); ?>
<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>
```

Neither renders anything. If I dsm($form) the variable looks correctly populated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I noticed that #printed = TRUE on all my form elements, so they are not being printed. Going to make a new question for why they are set that way.

Comment: Then just go ahead and set the printed value to false. Chances are they have been rendered somewhere else.

Comment: Ahh.  This helped me out.  Didn't think to look at the #printed property until I read this.

Answer (score 1):

To find the title you need to look at how the Exposed form does it. First it loops through all the widgets in the form `<?php foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>` then it prints the label `<label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">`.

If you explicitly want the title of the view then you are going to have to use a form_alter or a preprocess function to get it there.

Comment: You pointed my in the right direction. That template file doesn't use the form directly at all. Once I switched to printing the widgets instead it worked as I wanted it to.